# Netstream to Movieclip don't work

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a problem. 
I want to add an onClick method to netstream. 
I read that you need to turn on netstream movieclip. 
I did it, the problem is because the video is not displayed

```
private var nc:NetConnection;
    private var ns:NetStream;
    private var video:Video;
    private var adSoundTransform:SoundTransform;
    private var mc_flv:MovieClip;



    public function FakeAd(lineColor:Number, fillColor:Number, label:String)
    {


        function asyncErrorHandler(event:AsyncErrorEvent):void
        {

        }
        nc = new NetConnection();
        nc.connect(null);
        ns = new NetStream(nc);
        ns.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, this.asyncErrorHandler);

        ns.play("http://www.helpexamples.com/flash/video/cuepoints.flv");
        video = new Video(640,360);

        video.attachNetStream(ns);
        video.smoothing = true;
        //addChild(video);
        mc_flv.addChild(video);
        //ns.resume();


        //video.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
        //video.y = stage.stageHeight/2;

    mc_flv.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onClick);

    function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
        {

            navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://Google.com"));

        }
```

Comment: is mc_flv on stage? is it added? I can't see the addChild(mc_flv); anywhere.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/vastinspector_dual?player=flash&tag=http%3A%2F%2Fvpaid.megiteam.pl%2Fvpaid.xml     Now is the problem of video playback